# Changing date/time on an AWS EC2 instance causes the server to beccome unresponsive within about an hour

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, time, ntp

I have a program which runs on an EC2 instance.  The program is is time-driven, and written in go, so to test it, I can't use faketime - I have to change the time on the server.  The server is built from the Amazon Linux 2 AMI, with some extra agents, and runs fine in many (100s-1000s of instances) other cases, where the time is not modified.  The instance type is an  M5a.xlarge.

Google can't find any other instances where people are reporting issues changing time for testing on EC2 linux instances (or my search skills are not up to it).

If I change the time, the server runs OK for upto an hour or so, and then the load-average starts to climb, and it quickly becomes unresponsive.

The server has a single ENI (I did originally write that it had a second, but have simplified by removing that), and is using EFS.

Does anyone have experience setting time forwards on EC2 instances?

Update: having top running is useful as it shows that although the load average is climing, no single process is responsible (as far as I can see) - nothing in the process table is using > 1%

Further update: removing the second ENI makes no difference - at some random but less that around an hour - time, the server becomes unresponsive.

Comment: What processes are taking up load when looking at something like top?

Comment: None - the processes shown by top are system processes - nothing taking more than 1% of CPU time

Comment: Load averages includes processes in state D as well as R.  Those may not be on the top of the `top` display but they must be there somewhere.  Also check for memory usage - processes stuck swapping contribute to load average too (state D)

Comment: EFS and any logging/metric agents are not going to like the system time changing dramatically.Can you disable the agents before changing the time to rule them out? Can you try an EBS volume instead of EFS for your test?  Once a machine goes un-responsive can you reboot it and look at the logs? Does EFS still work after the reboot? If the machine is still broken after reboot remove the boot disk and attach it to a test ec2 instance as a secondary disk to access the logs.

Comment: @MisterSmith Thanks for all sensible suggestions.  Sadly I don't have access to do any of those, except for changing to EBS.   I wondered if the EFS was the problem - it does come back fine as it happens.  I'll try EBS, thanks.

Comment: @GrahamNicholls Did you figure out a solution to this issue? One of my instances seems to behave just like this.